Can not (fully) change language (specifically to German)
This is an example code illustrating the problem:
\documentclass{book}

    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \usepackage{varioref}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}

    \pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \part{A first part}
        \chapter{A first chapter}
            \section{Some images}
                \begin{figure}[H]
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image}
                    \caption{First example image}   \label{fig:one}
                \end{figure}
                \begin{figure}[H]
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image}
                    \caption{Second example image}  \label{fig:two}
                \end{figure}
                \begin{figure}[H]
                    \centering
                    \includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image}
                    \caption{Third example image}   \label{fig:three}
                \end{figure}
        \chapter{A second chapter}
            \section{Some list of things}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Thing nr. one     \label{item:one}
                    \item Thing nr. two     \label{item:two}
                    \item Thing nr. three   \label{item:three}
                    \item Thing nr. four    \label{item:four}
                    \item Thing nr. five    \label{item:five}
                \end{enumerate}
    \part{A second part}
        \chapter{A third chapter}
            \section{Some sample text}
                \blindtext[2]
            \section{Some more sample text}
                \blindtext[4]
        \chapter{A fourth chapter}
            \section{Referencing some of the above}
                See e.g. \vref{fig:one}, \vref{fig:three}, or alternatively refer to \vrefrange{item:two}{item:five}.
\end{document}

Compiling leaves me with the following results:



As can be seen, the chapter titles, figure captions and the blindtext has been translated correctly, yet here is the referencing page:

It is all in english! Instead of "1.1 on page 7" I would have expected to see "1.1 auf Seite 7" and so on.
Also, when I now try to overwrite the figure captions from "Abbildung" (figure) to, let's say, "Zeichnung" (sketch), it won't work, as babel seems to be able to overwrite the setting even though it is being set after loading the package... see in the following:
\documentclass{book}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Zeichnung}

    \usepackage{varioref}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}

    \pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

(this is the new head of the document)

As can be seen in the screenshot, it still keeps the same figure name "Abbildung" instead of the newly defined "Zeichnung".
Furthermore, when I try additionally loading the package ngerman into the document (declaring them in the head, read about this online when looking for fixes on my own), it generates the following output:

So anyways, can someone please propose a solution as well as telling me some more about my problem?

Try with \documentclass[ngerman]{book} so that the option also reaches the other packages.

You can rename the figures with something like \addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Quack}} 

you could use \usepackage[german]{varioref}

Under no circumstance should you load the ngerman package; please stick with \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}.

I suggest you make two changes:

set ngerman as a document class option rather than as just a package option (for babel):
\documentclass[ngerman]{book}


add the instruction
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

after loading varioref, in order to tell LaTeX to insert a "label" -- such as "Abbildung" -- before the associated figure number(s).


After making these two changes, the code block
See, e.g., \vref{fig:one}, \vref{fig:three}, or alternatively 
refer to \vrefrange{item:two}{item:five}.

will generate this output:

Of course, if you want abbreviated labels -- say, "Abb." instead of "Abbildung" -- just omit the option noabbrev.

Is it possible to also have \vref use the name that I changed by \addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Zeicnung}} ? As in it refering to "Zeichnung 1.1" instead of to "Abbildung 1.1" ?

@JonasBehr - If you don't load cleveref, \vref will not prefix a label (such as "Abbildung" or "Zeichnung") to the number of the figure environment. cleveref is programmed to use babel's language-specific defaults for label names. To override the default and obtain your preferred alternative for the figure label, viz., "Zeichnung" instead of "Abbildung", I suggest you  issue the instruction \crefname{figure}{Zeichnung}{Zeichnungen} (after loading cleveref, of course).

Alright, thanks a lot!

+1, but you forgot to recommend \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}.

@egreg - Oops, you've caught me in flagrante delicto. I'll try not to let it happen again... :-)

@Mico Penitentiagite
